# Load period-separated text file into db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I need to load an entire text file (contains only ASCII text) into the database (DB2 Express ed.). The table has only two columns `EXAMPLE_TABLE` (ID, TEXT). The `ID` column is PK, with auto generated data, whereas the text is `VARCHAR(50)`.

Now I need to use the load/import utility to save each sentence in the text face into the `EXAMPLE_TABLE`, that is, we have a row for each sentence. The row-id should be auto generated, but that is already specified in table creation time. The import utility should consider the period '.' as delimiter (otherwise I don't know how to extract sentences).

How can this be done in DB2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using delimited files, the standard DB2 `import` and `load` utilities do not have the ability to specify a row record terminator.  The `LF` character (or `CRLF` on Windows) is the only record terminator you can use.

So, you would need to pre-process your file (to either replace each period (`.`) with a newline or insert a newline after each period) before you can use `import` or `load`, resulting in a file with each sentence on a separate line.

You can do this with `tr`:

```
cat file | tr '.' '\n' > file.load
db2 "import from file.load of del insert into example_table (text)"
```

Keep in mind that you will probably also need to account for spaces after the period, so you don't end up with leading spaces at the beginning of each "sentence" in your table, and you may also want to account for additional whitespace (i.e. empty lines between each paragraph).